# How to print tables in slidify?

Tags: r, dataframe, slidify

I want to show contents of data.frame as a table in slidify.
I know how to create Markdown tables from data.frames using ascii library, but when I try to use it with slidify, instead of seeing the table in output html, I see a bunch of information about the inner structure of an ascii table.

So how do you print e.g. head(some.data.frame) in slidify?

Edit:

In fact I want to show a table of Views in CRAN Task Views,
Right now I typed the table manually in Markdown:

```
Views | Content
--------|--------
Bayesian| Bayesian Inference
ChemPhys| Chemometrics and Computational Physics
ClinicalTrials| Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis
```

I want to create this table automatically from `ctv` package. I have gathered my needed information in a data.frame:

```
library(ctv)
list.of.views <- available.views()
X <- data.frame(View=NA,Description=NA)
for(i in 1:length(list.of.views))
{
  X[i,1] <- list.of.views[[i]]$name
  X[i,2] <- list.of.views[[i]]$topic
}
head(X)
```

which results in

```
                   View                                     Description
1              Bayesian                              Bayesian Inference
2              ChemPhys          Chemometrics and Computational Physics
3        ClinicalTrials Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis
4               Cluster        Cluster Analysis & Finite Mixture Models
5 DifferentialEquations                          Differential Equations
6         Distributions                       Probability Distributions
```

I make markdown using `ascii` package

```
library(ascii)
print(ascii(X[1:6,1:2]), type = 'pandoc')
```

which shows this in R terminal:

```
    **View**                **Description**                                  
 --- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------
 1   Bayesian                Bayesian Inference                               
 2   ChemPhys                Chemometrics and Computational Physics           
 3   ClinicalTrials          Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis  
 4   Cluster                 Cluster Analysis & Finite Mixture Models         
 5   DifferentialEquations   Differential Equations                           
 6   Distributions           Probability Distributions                        
 --- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------

Warning messages:
1: In rep(rownames, length = nrow(x)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
2: In rep(colnames, length = ncol(x)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

but when this last `print` line in a code chunk in my `Rmd` file and `slidify` it, I see the following content in my slide:

```
## <S4 Type Object>
## attr(,".xData")
## <environment: 0x03b904d8>
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "asciiTable"
## attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
## [1] "ascii"
```

Comment: I am an `xtable` fan for some tasks but am using `pander` more frequently.  Search these packages.  There are others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to `Tyler Rinker` I managed to create the table I wanted using `xtable`

````
---
```{r, results='asis'}
print(xtable(X[1:6,1:2]), type = "html")
```
````

Comment: You can set `options(xtable.type = 'html')` in a setup chunk right at the top of your Rmd document. Then you can call `xtable` just like you would in the R console, without having to wrap it inside a `print` call and specify type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want markdown, I can strongly recommend my [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) package that can transform R objects to different dialects of markdown formats. Quick example:

1. Load the package

   ```
   library(pander)
   ```
2. Create a markdown table on your demo data with the default [multi-line format](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#multiline-tables) of Pandoc:

   ```
   > pander(X[1:6,1:2])

   -----------------------------------------------
           View                 Description       
   --------------------- -------------------------
         Bayesian           Bayesian Inference    

         ChemPhys            Chemometrics and     
                           Computational Physics  

      ClinicalTrials      Clinical Trial Design,  
                         Monitoring, and Analysis 

          Cluster        Cluster Analysis & Finite
                              Mixture Models      

   DifferentialEquations  Differential Equations  

       Distributions     Probability Distributions
   -----------------------------------------------
   ```
3. Or in [grid format](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#grid-tables):

   ```
   > pander(X[1:6,1:2], style = 'grid')

   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   |         View          |        Description        |
   +=======================+===========================+
   |       Bayesian        |    Bayesian Inference     |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   |       ChemPhys        |     Chemometrics and      |
   |                       |   Computational Physics   |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   |    ClinicalTrials     |  Clinical Trial Design,   |
   |                       | Monitoring, and Analysis  |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   |        Cluster        | Cluster Analysis & Finite |
   |                       |      Mixture Models       |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   | DifferentialEquations |  Differential Equations   |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   |     Distributions     | Probability Distributions |
   +-----------------------+---------------------------+
   ```
4. [Simple sytle](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#simple-tables) without automatic line breaks:

   ```
   > pander(X[1:6,1:2], style = 'simple', split.cells = Inf)

           View                            Description                  
   --------------------- -----------------------------------------------
         Bayesian                      Bayesian Inference               
         ChemPhys            Chemometrics and Computational Physics     
      ClinicalTrials     Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis
          Cluster           Cluster Analysis & Finite Mixture Models    
   DifferentialEquations             Differential Equations             
       Distributions                Probability Distributions
   ```
5. And the [PHP Extra Markdown/rmarkdown format](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pipe-tables):

   ```
   > pander(X[1:6,1:2], style = 'rmarkdown', split.cells = Inf)

   |         View          |                   Description                   |
   |:---------------------:|:-----------------------------------------------:|
   |       Bayesian        |               Bayesian Inference                |
   |       ChemPhys        |     Chemometrics and Computational Physics      |
   |    ClinicalTrials     | Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis |
   |        Cluster        |    Cluster Analysis & Finite Mixture Models     |
   | DifferentialEquations |             Differential Equations              |
   |     Distributions     |            Probability Distributions            |
   ```

There are bunch of [global or custom options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#pander-options) to tweak the tables (like alignment, split settings, highlight cells etc.)

Comment: WOW...just gave `pander` a try for printing array objects in a `slidify` presentation. Your 5th example was just what I was looking for and made it super easy to embed beautiful tabulations in an Rmarkdown document which could be `knit` into `slidify`. Thanks so much for such a useful tool!!!